# Int Object not Callable, very odd it seems

Tags: int, typeerror

So I have created a program to calculate integrals and I am modifying my data to fit a question I have to complete.

```
def z(x, gamma, c):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return ((x**(gamma-1))*exp(-x))/(c-((x**(gamma-1))*exp(-x)))
```

Is my modified version of my integral

I run into problems whenever I try to make the statement

```
newXValues = empty([101])
newXValues = np.arange(0,1.00,0.01)

cValues = empty([501])
cValues = np.arange(0,5.01,0.01) 

X2=empty([3])

for temp in range(2,5): #all gamma values
    for i in range (0,100): #all x values from 0 to 1
        test = "{0:.2g}".format(z(newXValues[i],temp,1))
        if test == "{0:.2g}".format(0.5): 
            print("Success at X Value:", newXValues[i], "End Value:", f(newXValues[i],2), "Gamma:",temp) 
            X2[tick2] = newXValues[i]
            tick2+=1
            break    

for i in range(0,3): #to cycle through the 3 max values
   for j in range(2,5): #gamma = 2 through 4
       for z in range(0,500): #all values for c
           test2 = "{0:.2g}".format(z(X2[tick3],j,cValues[z]))
           if test2 == "{0:.2g}".format(maxValues[i]):
               tick3+=1
               print("Successful C:",cValues[z], "Gamma:",j,"Max:",maxValues[i])
```

I get an error for

```
   test2 = "{0:.2g}".format(z(X2[tick3],j,cValues[z]))
```

Claiming "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" I don't get an error if I have a set value for gamma in the function z(x,gamma,c), but as soon as I introduce a for loop to cycle through the various values of gamma i get this error.

I would like to note, I am able to run the first for loop without any problems, it it the second set of for loops where the problem occurs. Even though they are almost the exact same

```
 test2 = "{0:.2g}".format(z(X2[tick3],j,cValues[z]))
 test = "{0:.2g}".format(z(newXValues[i],temp,1))
```

Comment: Hint: it happens when you override the definition of `z` inside the second for-loop: `for z in range(0,500):`

Comment: @alfasin I have never heard the term override, whats the best way to prevent it?

Comment: you're using the same variable name `z` in the for-loop so you're overriding the definition of the function inside the scope of the loop. Don't use the same name - use something else, there are plenty of other characters in  the alphabet ;)